# When is this particular "System.InvalidOperationException" raised?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

There are 2 projects.

1) A UserControl with a custom DataGrid.

2) A client app that uses this custom DataGrid UserControl.

The client app has a tab control with each tab using the custom DataGrid control.
The client app sends a DataTable to the DataGrid UserControl and this table is later converted to an ObservableCollection of DataRowView and set as the DataSource for the DataGrid in the UserControl.
There is a TwoWay binding set on all the columns of the DataGrid.
All the columns in the Grid are read-only.

Now when I attempt a Copy operation(Ctrl+C) on one of the grids, an Exception is generated

> A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'ID' of type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Here ID is the column name.

Setting the binding to OneWay fixes the issue. But I want to know why this exception is getting generated when I do a Copy operation only on one particular Tab. Copy works totally fine on all other tabs (with similar read-only properties set).

The exception sounds as a result of attempted modification. There is no change made to the DataContext. To make sure, I put a break-point in the DataContext changed event. This event is not hit when the Exception occurs. Under what scenarios will this particular Exception be raised?

Comment: This is always an issue. Can you please comment before giving a down-vote?

Comment: can you post your copy operation codes? using Reflection may cause this issue. btw i'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @WPFUser I'm using the default grid copy command. There is no custom copy code.